# angular 1.5 translate переводит в &#1058;&#1072;

Tags: angularjs, перевод

```
                <lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files='letterOfCompany'
                                     name="letterOfCompany"
                                     accept="image/*"
                                     lf-option="optionFileImages"
                                     lf-browse-label="{{'CHOOSE' | translate}}"
                                     lf-remove-label="{{'DELETE' | translate}}"
                                     lf-placeholder="jpg, jpeg, png, gif, tiff"
                                     preview
                                     drag
                                     lf-drag-and-drop-label="Переместите фото сюда"></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: проблема скорее в каком-то левом компоненте _lf-ng-md-file-input_

Comment: @Grundy, в md-checkbox также. Я не силен в английском, но если покопаться в документации к angular translate, то вроде как там надо различать пре и пост компиляционный перевод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');

```
angular.module('module.name')
    .config(["$translateProvider", function($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
    }]);
```

[$translateSanitization](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization)